# Website is Gzip compression enabled or disabled

Tags: .htaccess, compression, gzip, deflate, gtmetrix

Recently i inserted below code to my `.htaccess` file for enabling gzip compression.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Also i tested below one:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Both cases,some of famous website testers like [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com) reports it is gzip disabled and some of them like [varvy](https://varvy.com/tools/gzip/) reports, it is enabled. How to know which one is correct. My website is [agahichi.com](http://www.agahichi.com) and web server is litespeed.

Comment: First of all, Varvy is horribly unreliable. Disregard it completely. GtMetrix is better, but to be honest there is only one site checker you should use and that is [Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=agahichi.com) from Google. Which states your Gzip compression is **not** working.

Comment: @thickguru, Thank you, then how can i fix it? is there something wrong at my codes or is there something related to web server admin?

Comment: The code you've used looks fine to me. There is a chance something else in your `.htaccess` file is causing it to not run. Do you have anything else within the file?

Comment: @thickguru, i just removed all other things and again the same results.

Comment: Who do you use for hosting...? Only other reason I can think of as to why it is not working is because your provider does not support it... :/

Comment: The provider claims , all parameters set on server for gzip compression but i am not sure, because the server is public and as i know gzip compression uses more cpu. So, i don't know, maybe they are not honest with me.

Comment: If they're claiming that you can do it, then you should ask them for the specific code or make them do it for you. Because the code you're using above **is** correct and _should_ work. Therefore leading me to believe that their server does not support it.

Comment: Yes, Ok. i am trying to make them do it, but they try to escape from giving me any code.

Comment: Who is your hosting service..? You're paying them for a service which they're not providing fully. Therefore they are technically breaking contract.

Comment: www.bertina.ir, but they are still claim everything OK. They say, some of website can not check gzip compression correctly because of some settings on the server. Also they say, zlib.output_compression = 1 and output_buffering = off, so it's ok.